# Alternative to ganache

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, ethereumjs, ganache

can someone please tell me an alternative to Ganache? Tried installing ganache on my laptop and it's not supported. Ganache works on 64 bit computers and mine is 32bit. Is there a way I can go round this problem?
I have contracts I want to deploy but I can't because I don't have a local block chain. Or is there a way I can import the whole project file to remix IDE and run it there?

Comment: You can use TestRPC - https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/ethereum-and-clients/test-rpc/. It's really fast, I used it for few tests.

Comment: hi Miroslav, thank you very much. I installed it and it runs now but a new problem came up, when i use the "truffle migrate" command it migrates and mints a sucessful transaction but there is an error as it doesnt save the transaction to the chain. This is the error code                            ⠹ Saving migration to chain.
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at Migration._deploy (C:\Users\RCA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\migration.js:99:1)

Comment: just found a solution to the migration error. i had to downgrade the truffle version with $ npm i -g truffle@v5.0. Thanks a lot Miroslav!

Comment: Glad to help you!